# How to call onBrowserEvent() of EditTextCell programmatically from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, dom-events

**How to call onBrowserEvent of EditTextCell  programmatically  from Javascript ?**

I override onBrowserEvent in my customEditTextCell which is called when user click on cell. I also want to call from other event.

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
        NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) { 
     // my custom code is here
   }
```

When I am clicking cell then above method is called and 1 jQuery (picker) popup is opened.
On jQuery popup **Done** button is present.

**On click of Done button I want to call above gwt-java method, How to do it ?**

I know we can call java-gwt method from Javascript, but I am facing some problem while passing param like  context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater

How to pass **context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater** parameter from Javascript to gwt-java method ?

In my onmodule I called `registerOnBrowserEventForDateTimePicker()` and written following method: which wrong, gwtc compilation failed, please correct me.

**MyClass.java**

```
public static native void registerOnBrowserEventForDateTimePicker()  /*-{       
                $wnd.callOnBrowserEventForDateTimePicker =$entry@ui.gwtmassupdateui.client.widgets.TimestampPickerCell::
                callOnBrowserEventForDateTimePicker(com/google/gwt/cell/client/Cell/Context,com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element,Ljava/lang/String,com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent,com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent);
    }-*/;
```

Any sample code for the same or pointers to do it correctly

Comment: So basically you want to call the same method again, with the same parameters from your jquery code? Or else I don't understand your question.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata  Yes, I want to call the same method again, with the same parameters from your jquery code. with same context

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with another anonymous object that holds the context for the method. Something like this:

```
private Runnable contextCall;

public void onBrowserEvent(final Context context, final Element parent, final String value,
        final NativeEvent event, final ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) { 
    contextCall = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // my custom code is here
        }
    };

    contextCall.run();
}

public void callOnBrowserEventForDateTimePicker() {
    contextCall.run();
}
```